# Add dimension and metric data to array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-analytics

Using the following code (from the [Analytics quickstart](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php#3_setup_the_sample)), I am trying to add the dimension and metric data to the `$responseArray` array in order to return it as JSON later:

```
public function formatDailySessionsReport( $reports ) {
    $responseArray = array();
    for ( $reportIndex = 0; $reportIndex < count( $reports ); $reportIndex++ ) {
        $report = $reports[ $reportIndex ];
        $header = $report->getColumnHeader();
        $dimensionHeaders = $header->getDimensions();
        $metricHeaders = $header->getMetricHeader()->getMetricHeaderEntries();
        $rows = $report->getData()->getRows();

        for ( $rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex < count($rows); $rowIndex++) {
            $row = $rows[ $rowIndex ];
            $dimensions = $row->getDimensions();
            $metrics = $row->getMetrics();
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($dimensionHeaders) && $i < count($dimensions); $i++) {
                //Adding dimension data here
                $responseArray[$rowIndex][$i][$dimensionHeaders[$i]] = $dimensions[$i];
                //print($dimensionHeaders[$i] . ": " . $dimensions[$i] . "\n");
            }

            for ($j = 0; $j < count($metrics); $j++) {
                $values = $metrics[$j]->getValues();
                for ($k = 0; $k < count($values); $k++) {
                    $entry = $metricHeaders[$k];
                    //Adding metric data here
                    $responseArray[$j][$k][$entry->getName()] = $values[$k];
                    //print($entry->getName() . ": " . $values[$k] . "\n");
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    return $responseArray;      
}
```

When using the commented out `print` statement, the data appears to be printed correctly:

```
ga:date: 20170426
sessions: 2711
ga:date: 20170427
sessions: 2425
ga:date: 20170428
sessions: 2620
```

However when trying to add it to the array, the data does not seem to be formatted correctly (sessions only included once):

```
"response": [
    [
      {
        "ga:date": "20170426",
        "sessions": "656"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "ga:date": "20170427"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "ga:date": "20170428"
      }
    ],
    ...
]
```

I am using the following to create the JSON reponse:

```
$response = $this->formatDailySessionsReport( $reportData );
// Return response
echo json_encode( array( 'response' => $response ) );
```

I am expecting something more like this:

```
"response" [
  {
    "ga:date": "20170426",
    "sessions": "656"
  },
  {
    "ga:date": "20170427",
    "sessions": "1234"
  },
  {
    "ga:date": "20170428",
    "sessions": "1234"
  }  
]
```

with the dates and sessions included together, **how do I structure the `$responseArray` to get my expected format?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was using the incorrect index inside of my `for` loop:

```
for ( $rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex < count($rows); $rowIndex++) {
    $row = $rows[ $rowIndex ];
    $dimensions = $row->getDimensions();
    $metrics = $row->getMetrics();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($dimensionHeaders) && $i < count($dimensions); $i++) {
        $responseArray[$rowIndex][$i][$dimensionHeaders[$i]] = $dimensions[$i];
        //print($dimensionHeaders[$i] . ": " . $dimensions[$i] . "\n");
    }

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($metrics); $j++) {
        $values = $metrics[$j]->getValues();
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($values); $k++) {
            $entry = $metricHeaders[$k];
            $responseArray[$rowIndex][$k][$entry->getName()] = $values[$k];
            // wrong index ^^^^^^^^^ <-- Here
            //print($entry->getName() . ": " . $values[$k] . "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code with array_map(),

```
$responseArray['response'] = array_map(function($v){
  return $v[0];
}, $responseArray['response']);
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I still get the data returned in the same format. No change.

Comment: print_r($responseArray)  here.

Comment: `echo json_encode( array( 'response' => array_map(function($v){
  return $v[0];
}, $response) ) );`

Comment: Yes, that is exactly [how I have it in my code](http://imgur.com/Mtu1vRN), still the same response - http://imgur.com/a/YAu6A

Comment: No, you can see it the inner `[]` is gone.

Comment: Oh right, sorry, I see that now thanks. However, the sessions are still not included (except for the first one)?

Comment: have you notice that you haven't store all the session in teh responseArray except the first one.

Comment: No, perhaps I am missing something obvious, are you talking about this line `$responseArray[$j][$k][$entry->getName()] = $values[$k];`?

Comment: right, so as my question states, how do I get the sessions and dates included together?

Comment: where you get the print result with all sessions in your answer? I think you debug it is easy.

Comment: The print result comes from the commented out code - http://imgur.com/nBpvMXq - in that for loop is where sessions get added

Comment: but your $responseArray not has it